# How to change clock frequency in Android?

Tags: android, linux, cpu, frequency

I'm a new to software development on Android.

I want to make an application like [SetCPU](http://androinica.com/2010/03/04/make-your-rooted-android-phone-even-faster-with-setcpu-app-reviews/) that can manipulate CPU frequency in Android.

But I couldn't find some related APIs or materials.

**I want to know following two things sincerely.**

1. Are there APIs to change the CPU frequency in Android?
2. If not, are there some APIs in Linux?

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, please, dear god, DO NOT DO THIS.

Answer (score 16):

Some commands in ADB

Set Governor:

```
adb shell echo "userspace" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Set Frequency in KHz:

```
adb shell su -c "echo "702000" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
//min frequency
adb shell su -c "echo "384000" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq"  
//MAX frequency
adb shell su -c "echo "384000" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq"
```

Get current CPU Frequency:

```
adb shell cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

Show availables governors:

```
adb shell su -c "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors"
```

Disable service that overwrite cpu online file:

```
adb shell su -c "stop mpdecision"
```

It's necessary to do this before enabling or disabling core. mp decision is restarted if the system is restarted.

Disable core:

```
adb shell su -c "echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online"
```

If that doesn't work:

```
& chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
```

Comment: On nexus 5X, Google Pixel and Nexus 6P there is no service like mpdecision. Do you also know what is the equivalent service that overrides CPU frequency on these devices.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Java API to change the frequency of an Android device. The only way to do this is to get your hands dirty with the Kernel.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need to root your device

http://www.pokedev.com/setcpu/