# How to Set CPU frequency in Android?

Tags: android

I'm a research student and I'm trying to build a android application which sets a specific CPU frequency. Similar to SetCPU, but my application is going to be automatic based on my own algorithm. 
I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238959/how-to-change-clock-frequency-in-android) but that doesn't give any clue about where to start. I'm ready to work on kernal or OS level as my project is just a demo one and will not be released for users. Please provide any suggestions to where I can start or any sample code which I can refer to get started.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source application called [Performance Control](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2401988) which requires root access and android 4.0+.
You can do a lot of stuff including changing the CPU frequency with it. You can see the complete feature list in the official thread [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2401988) and refer to the soucre code on [github](https://github.com/horn3t/PerformanceControl) for the code to change CPU freq programitically.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please provide an answer to the question instead of links to resources

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure about the actual code he wanted, but he asked for a direction  for where he can start.. I just showed him a open source application which he can refer and implement whatever he needs...